# Missing package "metro/src/lib/attachWebsocketServer"

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

After creating a new react-native expo project using `npx expo init app-name`.
In the project folder, I ran `npx expo start` but I always get this error.
Please check the screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luX5h.png)

I need help on this, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just use `npm install -g expo@latest expo-cli@latest` and everything should work fine.

Comment: Then I get Cannot find module 'metro-core'. Expo sucks!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade expo version by using `npm i expo --location=global` I had the same problem last week.

Comment: I used the same command and the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this happened because of the new React native. So I did
`npx expo init --template@44.0.0 my-app` and it worked.

Comment: receiving `error: unknown option `--template@44.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I used sudo it worked. I am on Ubuntu

```
sudo expo start
```